# StackStorm chatops with Mattermost has no result return

Tags: devops, hubot, chatops

I am using StackStorm chatops with **Mattermost Hubot adapter**,
however, I can't see any result return from my bot, but I can see an Ack from it, I have checked my console history, and didn't see any error about post_result action, what's wrong with it?

Comment: I have refered stackstorm [ChatOps Troubleshooting Guide](https://docs.stackstorm.com/troubleshooting/basic_chatops_troubleshooting.html), and I am sure that hubot has connected to StackStorm stream.

Comment: my st2 version:
$ st2 --version
st2 2.9.1, on Python 2.7.12